# How to write a grammar that handles inline comments in a comma seperated list?

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr4, grammar

I am trying to parse this list:

```
[Params]
        Param1 =
                0,                      $ reserved, shall equal 0
                ,,                      $ Link Path Size, Link Path
                0x0000,                 $ Descriptor
                0xC4,                   $ Data Type
                4,                      $ Data Size in bytes
                "posX",                 $ name
                "mm",                   $ units
                "X coordinate of current position",    $ help string
                ,,0,                    $ min, max, default data values
                ,,,,                    $ mult, div, base, offset scaling
                ,,,,                    $ mult, div, base, offset links
                ;                       $ decimal places
```

From what I can tell comments can be at the end of a line only. But here the comments are in the middle of the list. Since the list can span multiple lines. Note also that the list can have empty values.

Here is my current grammar:

```
grammar test;

eds                 :   section+;

section             :   header HEADER_DECl_END body;

header              :   '[' name ']';

body                :   field+;

field               :   name '=' value STMTEND;

name                :   Identifier;

raw_value           :   string
                    |   integer
                    |   hex
                    |   version
                    |   date
                    |   time;

value               :   raw_value
                    |   list;

list                :   raw_value list_value+;

list_value          :   ',' raw_value
                    |   ',';

string              :   String_standard
                    |   string_list;

string_list         :   String_standard string_list
                    |   String_standard String_standard;

integer             :   Integer;
version             :   Version;
date                :   Date;
time                :   Time;
hex                 :   Hex;

String_standard     :   '"' ( Escape | ~('\'' | '\\' | '\n' | '\r') | '.' | '+' + '/' | ' ') + '"';
 
Escape              :   '\\' ( '\'' | '\\' );

Integer             :   NUMBER+;

Hex                 :   '0' 'x' HEX_DIGIT+;

Version             :   NUMBER+ '.' NUMBER+
                    |   NUMBER+ '.' NUMBER+ '.' NUMBER+
                    |   NUMBER+ '.' NUMBER+ '.' NUMBER+ '.' NUMBER+;

Date                :   NUMBER NUMBER '-' NUMBER NUMBER '-' NUMBER NUMBER NUMBER NUMBER;

Time                :   NUMBER NUMBER ':' NUMBER NUMBER ':' NUMBER NUMBER;

Identifier          :   Identifier_Char+;

fragment 
Identifier_Char     :   LETTER
                    |   NUMBER
                    |   '_';


fragment LETTER              :   [a-zA-Z];

fragment HEX_DIGIT           :   [a-fA-F0-9];

fragment NUMBER              :   [0-9];

STMTEND             :   SEMICOLON NEWLINE+;
HEADER_DECl_END     :   NEWLINE;

fragment SEMICOLON : ';';
fragment NEWLINE   : '\r' '\n' | '\n' | '\r';

WS                  : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;
COMMENT             : '$' .*? NEWLINE? -> skip;
```

When I parse with this though it fails to parse the whole list. And terminates the list at the first comment. If I remove the comments my grammar works. So it works on this input:

```
[Params]
        Param1 =
                0,                      
                ,,                      
                0x0000,                 
                0xC4,                   
                4,                     
                "posX",              
                "mm",                
                "X coordinate of current position",  
                ,,0,                   
                ,,,,                   
                ,,,,                  
                ;
```

What do I need to do to handle the comments?

Comment: I find your whitespace handling confusing. You both ignore newlines and recognise them as part of tokens. I think `STMTEND` will fail to match if there is a space (or comment) between the semicolon and the newline, for example. That's not your problem, I don't think, because you say that your parse fails before the semicolon is reached. But it might be something you would want to address.

Comment: Okay, thanks! Yeah I wasn't quite sure how to handle that, because sometimes white space is important it looks like but other times it isn't. I'm new to antlr so it's all a bit confusing and I'm not sure how to handle it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are comment rules for Java:

```
WS:                 [ \t\r\n\u000C]+ -> channel(HIDDEN);
COMMENT:            '/*' .*? '*/'    -> channel(HIDDEN);
LINE_COMMENT:       '//' ~[\r\n]*    -> channel(HIDDEN);
```

You don’t have the inline comments, so something like:

```
WS:                 [ \t\r\n\u000C]+ -> channel(HIDDEN);
LINE_COMMENT:       '$' ~[\r\n]*    -> channel(HIDDEN);
```

Should do the trick (pretty sure you can `skip` if you don’t want them on the `HIDDEN` channel)